# Fractional equation A=B and its LCD

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $A(x)=B(x)$ be a fractional equation, and let $L(x)$ be the least common denominator of $A(x)=B(x)$. (For example, if $A(x)=B(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}=2$, $L(x)$ is $x(x-1)$)

Disprove the following statement:

"For any fractional equation $A(x)=B(x)$ and its least common denominator $L(x)$, $L(x)=0 \Rightarrow A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$."

background: Some people I know claim that the above statement is true because both sides of $A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$ equal zero.

Thank you.

Comment: But $A(x)L(x)$ has no denominator, neither does $B(x)L(x)$.

Comment: Gerry Myerson/ You are talking about the case where $L(x)$ and the denominator of $A(x)$ have already been canceled out, right?

Comment: I'm talking about $A(x)L(x)$, which is $2x-1$ in your example.

Comment: Gerry Myerson/ I see. In that case, I believe you agree with the following.

If $A(x)=B(x)$ is $\frac{2}{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}=1$, then $L(x)$ is $x^2-1$ and $A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$ is $x^2+x-2=0$. Now $L(x)=0 \iff x^2-1=0 \iff x=-1 \vee x=1$, and $A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x) \iff x^2+x-2=0 \iff x=-2 \vee x=1$. Because $x=-1 \vee x=1 \Rightarrow x=-2 \vee x=1$ is not true, $L(x)=0 \Rightarrow A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$ is false in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. It is not news that algebraic manipulations can introduce extraneous roots, and that it pays to check any alleged solutions in the original equation to see whether they actually work. $AL=BL$ has 2 solutions, one of which is a solution of $A=B$, the other of which is extraneous.

Comment: Everything you're saying is right, but it's not what I'm talking about. My point is that "not every solution of $L(x)=0$ is a solution of $A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$." I'm saying this because some people assert that "for any fractional equation $A(x)=B(x)$, every solution of $L(x)=0$ is a solution of $A(x)L(x)=B(x)L(x)$." What do you think?